# Maximum upload size fileuploader ASP per fil

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp-classic

When I have 3 asp fileupload controls on a page, by default I can upload files up to 4MB. Inside the web.config you can change the maximum upload size like this:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="15360" />
```

Now, in the above example you can upload 15MB of files in total, which means when I upload a 10MB file in the first fileupload, I can only upload 2 more files that together have less than 5MB filesize , but that is not what I am looking for. For each file I want the upload size to be 15MB.

So instead of this:

1. File one (10MB)
2. File two (4MB)
3. File three (1MB)

I need this:

1. File one (15MB)
2. File two (15MB)
3. File three (15MB)

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you need to check this in code-behind

```
int maxSingleFileLength = 15728640; // 15MB = 1024 * 1024 * 15

if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > maxSingleFileLength )
{
    // error message here
}
```

Also, do not forget to increase config value to be able to post 3 x 15MB.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="46080" />
```